# How to merge a pull request without getting a merge commit in the Git history

Tags: git, github

On Github every time I merge a pull request into my base branch I get an extra merge commit:

> Merge pull request #77 ...

I prefer to get a git history without these merge commits.

How can I achieve that?

Comment: `git merge --squash`

Comment: This will combine all commits into one.

Comment: Jop correct, and then it applies the squash commit as single commit on your HEAD without creating a parent relationship to the 'pull request' branch. See [here](https://github.com/blog/2141-squash-your-commits)

Comment: Do a rebase instead of a merge, optionally squashing the commits as well but not really necessary most of the time. This will relocate and reapply the same commits on top of your current branch tip and avoid the merge commit. However, you have now rewritten the history so whoever owns the repository where the pull request came from is best to update his repository according to your rewrite or you will get a similar pull request with the same commits later.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen I usually don't use the PR branch again after merging the PR so it's not an issue for me.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

To get a git history without any pull request merge commits I can use the merge button (Pull request page) and perform a rebase and merge:

[image]

Comment: The problem is 'Squash and merge' and 'Rebase and merge' both will lose gpg sign

Comment: Is there a way to prevent GH from generating new commits (with new hashes) during this if the source branch is based on the target branch?

Comment: @x-q-kuang is there a way to avoid this?

Answer (score 12):

Here are your options:

- Squash
- Rebase
- Merge

A squash will result in a single new commit representing all changes at the head of the main branch.  It is a special case of rebase.

A rebase will result in one or more new commits (any or all of which may be in a "broken"/unbuildable state) at the head of the main branch.

A merge creates a merge commit and leaves history as it really happened.

Here is documentation of the options: https://github.com/blog/2243-rebase-and-merge-pull-requests